# How To Refresh SidenavComponent Adn reload data on sidebar from another component on api call using angular 6? want to refresh image on sidebar

Tags: angular, typescript

How To Refresh SidenavComponent and reload data on sidebar from another component on api call  using angular 6? want to refresh image on sidebar.

Comment: Check out this guide: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: You can also create a service to communicate between the two components. Be careful to add `providedIn: 'root'` to see the same service in every module and component. (Singleton pattern)